# Airpods 2 state light remains orange

Tags: airpods, bluetooth

I lost my right airpod so I ordered a replacement to apple. Today they have sent me another right airpod. The problem is the following. I ve been charging them for a while, >20min. So when I try to hard reset them pressing the back button for more than 15sec it remains orange and it is not changing to white.

The curious thing is that I can pair them separately, it means I can pair the right one and I can pair the left one and both are fully charged but I am not able to pair them together.

How can I pair these together?